# Looking for home sale data

Tags: data-request, real-estate

I'm looking for home sale data that includes info such as an address, sale price, home type, sq. ft., etc.  Where (what dataset(s)) can I get that data from?

Comment: Can you add what geographical region you are interested in?

Comment: @philshem, Default to whole nation?

Answer (score 3):

nationwide, the biggest and best data set you're going to get is

http://asdfree.com/home-mortgage-disclosure-act-hmda.html

but if you can use a survey instead, start with

http://asdfree.com/american-housing-survey-ahs.html

and check other surveys on asdfree.com that have household-level statistics like acs, nychvs, and maybe scf

this is also worth a read

[How to construct a database with the underlying real estate data displayed by Redfin, Zillow, or Trulia?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/how-to-construct-a-database-with-the-underlying-real-estate-data-displayed-by-re)