# US House Sale Data

Tags: data-request, data.gov, real-estate

In the UK we have open data which gives up to date information on house transactions. This includes the address of the home and the price it sold for. It includes detailed data on the type of property. It does not include names of those involved etc.

Is there any similar data open or otherwise for the US?

Comment: i would be happy to know where i find such an open data in the UK ?

Comment: @elia-besh Here you go: http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/

Comment: It seems there is no US housing Open Data available with all the details of the transactions, then??
While we have it in more and more countries in Europe.

Comment: The US is a *much* larger area than most European countries. Many functions that are handled by the centralized national government in small countries, in the US are handled by lower levels of government (state, county and municipal). Thus there's no centralized national source of data for these functions. You might as well ask for a database of house sales *for all of Europe*.

Answer (score 4):

- [Historical graph of US new housing starts](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/graph/?graph_id=257777&category_id=). It measures the building of new houses. Which isn't as telling as it used to be because in some cases, in some areas, it's cheaper to build a brand new house then fix up an old one.
- [Existing US home sales](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/HOSINVUSM495N). Monthly graph and you can "stretch" the time span you want like the Google stock graphs.
- [And a search for more housing graphs](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/search?st=house+sales) at the Federal Reserve site. Free account, where you can create your own "dashboards" with a set of your own graphs. Fun!

NOTE: Some of the graphs above seem new as their data only goes back to 2015. But poke around, you will find something useful. The Federal Reserve has all kinds of graphs there about many aspects of the US economy and the historical graphs are really useful.

Answer (score 3):

The property appraisers from each county are able to provide this data.

Additionally, this previous answer had some information: [Looking for home sale data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4736/looking-for-home-sale-data?rq=1)

Taken from this post ([How to construct a database with the underlying real estate data displayed by Redfin, Zillow, or Trulia?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2019/how-to-construct-a-database-with-the-underlying-real-estate-data-displayed-by-re)

Denver, CO
http://data.denvergov.org/dataset/city-and-county-of-denver-parcels

Madison, WI
https://data.cityofmadison.com/Property/Assessor-Property-Information/u7ns-6d4x

New York, NY
http://www.nyc.gov/html/dcp/html/bytes/dwn_pluto_mappluto.shtml

Vancouver, BC
ftp://webftp.vancouver.ca/OpenData/csv/property_tax_report_csv.zip

Answer (score 3):

Quandl has some free real estate data:

The Zillow database shows home prices and rents by size, type and tier, housing supply, demand and sales etc: https://www.quandl.com/data/ZILL

The National Association of Realtors database shows average and median home prices by area and dwelling type: https://www.quandl.com/data/NAR

The Freddie Mac database shows house price indexes for various American cities as well as historical mortgage rates: https://www.quandl.com/data/FMAC

Hope this helps! Disclosure: I work for Quandl.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly "open" data, but the largest nationwide database about houses is maintained by [Zillow](http://www.zillow.com/?semAdid=66282859862&semKwid=kwd-570802407&semAdgid=4644069062&semMaTy=e&k_clickid=b0dae881-74ad-46a0-854a-7212c60e9856&gclid=Cj0KEQjwwry8BRDjsbjMpPSDvagBEiQA5oW0nAaP3T231-5GGPnzNPqODAwqmTLIoS1Mz_Jj5REm84UaAo6O8P8HAQ).

Their proprietary estimates of home prices are called "Zestimates."

Comment: Zillow does not have transaction level data as the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

The analogous database in the U.S. is called the Multiple Listing Service (MLS). But there are two problems with using it as an open data source.

1. It's decentralized. There is not one MLS. There are thousands. Each deals with a local area roughly the size of a city.
2. It's private. The MLS is owned and operated by the local Realtor's association. Realtor's are a private association of licensed real estate agents and brokers responsible for conducting and regulating real estate transactions by their agents.

[Lack of access to transaction level sales data is the reason Zillow's median error on its valuation estimates are currently still between four and five percent.](https://www.seattletimes.com/business/real-estate/how-accurate-are-zestimates-zillow-awards-1-million-to-trio-for-improving-them/)