# Property transactions datasets in Europe

Tags: data-request, europe, real-estate

I am looking for data on real estate transactions for as many countries as possible in Europe. These data would ideally include a home's exact location, the transaction price, the transaction date, home characteristics (e.g. number of bedrooms), and information about the transaction (like whether or not it was an arm's length transaction). I have found (via [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7635/us-house-sale-data)]) data like this on the UK, and am now looking for comparable data elsewhere in Europe. Similar datasets in the US context include [ZTRAX](https://www.zillow.com/research/ztrax/) and CoreLogic's transactions dataset. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In The Netherlands the [Cadastre](https://www.kadaster.nl/about-us) [sells this data](https://www.kadaster.nl/zakelijk/producten/vastgoed/woningtransacties) from 75 euro. You'll get (loosely translated most relevant points from Dutch):

> transaction date
> transaction price
> cadastral reference
> address of real estate
> cadastral size

I am not endorsing this product, nor have I worked with it, so I can't comment on the quality.